# Anchors not working on foreach-generated node names: "Unknown operator `c' or `ce' (in '0.center')."

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, anchor

So I try to generate a tikzpicture for the Pascal Triangle.
This is my code & result so far:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \n in {0,...,7}{
        \foreach \k in {0,...,\n}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro\nten{\n * 8}
            \node[rectangle,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm,draw,fill=Red!\nten] (a\k\n) at (\k-\n/2,7-\n) {$\binom{\n}{\k}$};
            \pgfmathsetmacro\currbinom{\xinttheiiexpr binomial(\n,\k)\relax}
            \node[rectangle,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm,draw,fill=Red!\nten] (b\k\n) at (\k-\n/2+10,7-\n) {$\currbinom$};
        };
    };
    %verbindungen
    \foreach \n in {0,...,6}{
        \foreach \k in {0,...,\n}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro\kp{\k+1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\np{\n+1}
            \draw[->] (a\k\n.center) -- (a\k\np);
        };
    };
    \node[rectangle] (eqsign) at (5,4) {$=$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:pascal-tri}
\end{figure}
```

This is the result:
[image: Pascal Triangle, but with wrong arrows]

However, I want to have connections between the centers, so I added ".center" to draw the lines to the center anchor:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \n in {0,...,7}{
        \foreach \k in {0,...,\n}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro\nten{\n * 8}
            \node[rectangle,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm,draw,fill=Red!\nten] (a\k\n) at (\k-\n/2,7-\n) {$\binom{\n}{\k}$};
            \pgfmathsetmacro\currbinom{\xinttheiiexpr binomial(\n,\k)\relax}
            \node[rectangle,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm,draw,fill=Red!\nten] (b\k\n) at (\k-\n/2+10,7-\n) {$\currbinom$};
        };
    };
    %verbindungen
    \foreach \n in {0,...,6}{
        \foreach \k in {0,...,\n}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro\kp{\k+1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\np{\n+1}
            \draw[->] (a\k\n.center) -- (a\k\np.center);
        };
    };
    \node[rectangle] (eqsign) at (5,4) {$=$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:pascal-tri}
\end{figure}
```

But then, I get the following error:
[image: Error when adding anchors to the second node]

How to fix it / what is wrong? Why is `a\k\n.center` working correctly, but `a\k\np.center` not?

Comment: don't show only snippets, always show a complete example, then we can test without having to guess how all the commands are defined.

Comment: Welcome! I can't compile your code, for unrelated errors or lack of packages you are using. Please, add to your snippet the minimum infrastructure so that we can just copy and paste and compile. See here for instructions: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: You want to use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` instead of `\pgfmathsetmacro` to explicitly get an integer number. Otherwise `\np` will be `?.0` and that decimal dot will be interpreted as the delimiter between node name and anchor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want `\pgfmathsetmacro`, but `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` to get an integer representation. Similarly, the macro for the binomial coefficient's value can/should be defined with `\edef`.

By the way, it's better to define a style instead of repeating long lists of options: much more manageable. Besides, `\foreach` cycles aren't PGF statements, so they should not be followed by semicolons (you get loads of warnings about `;` not existing in `\nullfont`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  rect/.style={rectangle,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm,draw,fill=Red!\nten}
]
\foreach \n in {0,...,7}{
  \foreach \k in {0,...,\n}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\nten{\n * 8}
    \node[rect] (a\k\n) at (\k-\n/2,7-\n) {$\binom{\n}{\k}$};
    \edef\currbinom{\xinttheiiexpr binomial(\n,\k)\relax}
    \node[rect] (b\k\n) at (\k-\n/2+10,7-\n) {$\currbinom$};
  }
}
%verbindungen
\foreach \n in {0,...,6}{
  \foreach \k in {0,...,\n}{
%    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\kp{\k+1}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\np{\n+1}
    \draw[->] ({a\k\n}.center) -- ({a\k\np}.center);
  }
}
\node[rectangle] (eqsign) at (5,4) {$=$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:pascal-tri}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use `\fpeval{fact(\n)/ (fact(\k)  * fact(\n-\k))}` instead of `\edef\currbinom{\xinttheiiexpr binomial(\n,\k)\relax}`?

Comment: @pascal974 Not really; `\xinttheiiexpr` can deal with larger coefficients.

Comment: thank you, I didn't know about this package

Comment: Thank you so much! This was 100% my problem & it works now with the truncate cmd.